# What does offset in java.lang.String holds?

Tags: java, string, offset

In String class of java, there is a variable defined as below:

```
private final int offset;
```

What does this offset hold?

Comment: The answer is in the very source file containing this variable.

Comment: Upgrade your Java version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From comment of variable offset:

> The offset is the first index of the storage that is used.

Internally a `String` is represented as a *sequence of chars in an array*.

This is the first char to use from the array.

It has been introducted because some operations like `substring` create a new `String` using the **original char array using a different offset**.

So basically is a variable introduced for a performance tuning for substring operations.

**Note:** the `offset` variable is always with the variable `private final int count;`

Answer (score 3):

Form the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java):

> The offset is the first index of the storage that is used.

Answer (score 3):

From [String.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html):

> The offset is the first index of the storage that is used.

```
/** The value is used for character storage. */
private final char value[];

/** The offset is the first index of the storage that is used. */    
private final int offset;
```

You can see it being used in various methods such as:

```
public char charAt(int index) {
    // ...
    return value[index + offset];
}
```